# DocuSign creates the envelope via API but no e-mail are sent

Tags: docusignapi

And thanks in advance for any help !

When I create en envelope with the status "sent", the signers does not get e-mail any more.
Friday morning, everything was working I was receiving e-mail.
But since friday noon, i can not receive a single e-mail (for recipients).

When I use: `envelopeApi.createEnvelope(this.config.accountId, { envelopeDefinition })`
My code receive:

```json
{
  "envelopeId": "xxx",
  "status": "sent",
  "statusDateTime": "2021-07-26T09:29:11.1800000Z",
  "uri": "/envelopes/xxx"
}
```

And When I check in the envelope administration panel, I see
[image]

If I try to create the envelope from the administration panel, emails are sent but not from API calls...

**Is it my account which limited or did I missed something?**

Complete code example:

```
  async testSendEnvelope2() {
    const signers: TemplateRole[] = [
      {
        email: 'sirko.alexandre@gmail.com',
        name: 'alexander',
        clientUserId: 'toto',
        tabs: {
          textTabs: [
            {
              tabLabel: 'toto',
              locked: 'true',
              required: 'true',
              value: 'blabla',
            },
          ],
        },
        roleName: 'Freeluper',
      },
      {
        email: 'alexandre@jump-biz.com',
        name: 'jalexandre',
        clientUserId: 'titi',
        tabs: {
          textTabs: [
            {
              tabLabel: 'titi',
              locked: 'true',
              required: 'true',
              value: 'blibli',
            },
          ],
        },
        roleName: 'Company',
      },
    ];

    const env: EnvelopeDefinition = {
      emailSubject: 'le sujet du mail',
      status: 'sent',
      templateId: 'xxx',
      templateRoles: signers,
    };
    const results = await this.docusignService.sendEnvelope(env);
    console.log(results);
  }
```

And `this.docusignService.sendEnvelope` simply calls the envelopeApi.createEnvelope (with credentials)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Re: Why aren't my recipients receiving email invitations to the signing ceremony?

The reason is that you are setting the `clientUserId` attribute for the recipient objects.

When you do that, the recipients become `captive` (`embedded`) recipients. In this case, email is not sent since the assumption is that you want your application to offer the signing ceremony to them.

If you want to record recipient metadata without causing the recipients to become embedded signers, use the [customFields attribute](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/create/#schema__envelopedefinition_recipients_signers_customfields)

### Re: Limitations for developer accounts?

The main limitations for the developer (demo) accounts are:

- the envelopes cannot be used for legally binding agreements
- the envelopes are cleared out periodically.

### Re slow email

On rare occasions the developer system gets a bit backed up and email delivery is slow.

A way to check is to use the [DocuSign web app](https://demo.docusign.net) to send a test envelope from your developer account. If it works then you should suspect your API app.

Comment: I checked spams and tried 3 different email provider (our company mail, gmail and yopmail).
On the administration panel in docusign, the envolope is marked as sent and if I use the "resend" button, nothing happen
If I create the envelope with the administration panel, the e-mail is sent correctly

Comment: Sorry, I followed your question rather than looking at your JSON. Corrected the answer.

Comment: Thank you a lot that was it!
An thanks a lot for complements (I was indeed trying to pass metadata with clientUserId)